# iOS app submission process - Submitting app for a third party

Tags: ios, app-store

I've been reading loads of Apple docs and SO questions lately about this topic, and all I can say is that my head is full of concepts like bundle id, app id, certificates... but I'd need your help to clarify.
I have an apple developer certificate, that was used to develop an app for a third party. Several provisioning profiles for ad-hoc distribution were created, in order to let the client testing the app. It was signed with the iOS Wildcard AppID and everything went fine. Now that the day of uploading the app is getting closer, I'd like to change the bundle id. So, first question:

- If the bundle id is changed, will the client be able to test the app with the same provisioning profile I've provided them before?

In order to submit the app, a new record in iTunes Connect must be created. Marketing and sales stuff can be managed from this platform:

- As the application is for a client, should it be submitted through a client's apple account? He would create an user with acces to manage applications for me, and I could submit the app signed with a distribution profile created by myself, is this right?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**If the bundle id is changed, will the client be able to test the app with the same provisioning profile I've provided them before?**"

I may be wrong but after using Test Flight, I started to realise, the reason why one can put an app on a device is because the provisioning profile has certain device id marked as part of that "group". Your provisioning profile is like a group, if your device ID is not part of that group, then you can't put the app on your device.

For testing, you should use Test Flight, it allows you to send apple binary over the air (assuming you've added your client's device ID to your provisioning profile and refreshed your provision profiles in Xcode)

"**As the application is for a client, should it be submitted through a client's apple account?**"

If your client is fine with it being under your own company's name, then you can submit the app using your Apple ID. Otherwise, he'll need to probably add you to his iOS developer account.

Comment: Thanks!! And what about generating a new app ID for the release (I've been developing with the Wildcard App ID)?? I would create after a distribution profile for the app store with that ID, but the client would be able to keep on testing wit his ad-hoc provisioning profile, as long as I sign the archive with the wildcard, is this right? And the way that Apple would know that the app I upload with the new ID is right, it's because I would've pointed out the bundle id when generated that app ID, isn't it? Please, don't say no, I think I'm getting to understand it :)

Comment: I don't see why you can't just keep your client on the development profile, and when the app is ready, you can just submit the app. The client using the development profile will be able to test your app and if he wants to test the live version, well, there's nothing stopping him from downloading it form iTunes app store. When you view/edit a provisioning profile, you will see the "App ID" as well as the "Device IDs". These two things essentially say which device can install this app for the specified App ID.

Answer (score 0):

If the client owns the app, wants to be listed as the seller of the app, and wants to control the app (description, availability, price), then the app should be submitted under the clients account using the clients bundle ID and a Distribution certificate created using the client's iOS Developer account.